# How to calculate time complexity?

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity

I've gone through some basic concepts of calculating time complexities. I would like to know the time complexity of the code that follows.

I think the time complexity would be O(log<sub>3</sub>n*n<sup>2</sup>). It may still be wrong and I want to know the exact answer and how to arrive at the same. Thank you :)

```
  function(int n){
     if(n == 1) return;
     for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
           printf("*");
     function(n-3);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two nested loops with *n* iterations give *O(n^2)*. Recursion calls the function itself for *O(n)*-time since it decreases *n* for the constant 3, thus it's called *n/3 + 1 = O(n)* times. In total, it's *O(n^3)*.

The logarithm constant in your result would be in case that function is called with the value of *n/3*.

Comment: If n is divided by 3 instead of subtraction, then is his answer correct?